# OLS without covariates

Tags: regression, least-squares

Linear model without covariates

$$y_i=a+\epsilon_i$$

I'm trying to calculate the $\hat{a}$ using OLS by $min\sum(y_i-a)^2$.
$$\frac{d}{d(a)}\sum(y_i-a)^2=0$$
$$\sum y_i=n \hat{a}$$
$$ \hat{a}=\frac{\sum y_i}{n} =\bar{y}.$$

Now for $E(\hat{a})$:

$$\hat{a}=\frac{\sum (a+\epsilon_i)}{n}=a+\frac{\sum \epsilon_i}{n}$$

But if I well understood the idea of $\epsilon$, $\sum \epsilon_i=0$.

So, $$\hat{a}=\bar{y}=a ???$$

Where was the problem ?

Comment: With $i=1,2,3,...n$

Comment: You forgot to take the expectation.

Comment: You took $E(\hat{a})$ and showed that was $a$ ... but then just started writing $\hat a$ instead of $E(\hat{a})$... why?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the case that $n^{-1} \sum \epsilon = 0$. However, it *is* the case that $n^{-1} \sum \epsilon \to \mathbb{E}(\epsilon) $ (due to the law of large numbers), and the assumption about the error term is that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$.

In other words, $\hat{a} \to a$, meaning that the sample average is a consistent estimator for $a$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which concerns computing $\mathbb{E}(\hat a)$.

Comment: OP finds that $\hat{a} = a$ and asks what goes wrong. I show what goes wrong (sample average confused with expectation).

Comment: The only thing that went wrong is the OP did not take the expectation.  Convergence with $n$ is not part of the question, nor is it part of its solution.

Comment: OP explicitly writes "But if I well understood the idea of $\epsilon$, $\sum \epsilon = 0$", and this is not true.

Comment: Your are correct.  The solution is to point out that $\mathbb{E}\left(\sum\epsilon\right)=0$ *is* true.

Comment: @Superpronker  Yes but the expectation of each epsilon is 0 and so also is the expectation of the finite sum. This was Bill Huber's point.  I think you and the OP are just getting hung up by the notation being used.

Comment: I appreciate that @whuber is right: OP forgot to take an expectation. However, in the next line OP, is not working with the expectation of $\hat{a}$. Instead, he is working directly on $\hat{a}$ and re-writing the numerator. Hence, you can disregard OP saying "Now for $E(\hat{a})$". I guess several mistakes are made, it depends on which you choose to follow.

Comment: The OP seems to confuse errors with residuals. $\epsilon$ is the error so $\sum \epsilon_i \neq 0$ (almost surely), but we do assume that $E(\epsilon_i)=0$. On the other hand by construction we have that $\sum \hat \epsilon_i = 0$, where $\hat \epsilon_i = y_i- \hat a$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, I agree